# Ifort mkl lapack eigenvalue

Tags: fortran, lapack, eigenvalue

I am using ifort 14.0, mkl and the f95 lapack interfaces to do some eigenvalue decompositon.

The function I am using currently is DSYEV_F95, which is called either:

```
        call DSYEV_F95(A=RMEigenVectors,W=RVEigenValues,Info=ISTmp&
      &,JobZ="N")
```

producing eigen value only, or

```
        call DSYEV_F95(A=RMEigenVectors,W=RVEigenValues,Info=ISTmp&
      &,JobZ="V")
```

which also returns the eigen vectors.

However, using call one, the first three eigenvalues of a given 100x100 matrix were:

-0.00000000000000022204
 1.01690323906836455059
 1.04051353339583818602

whereas the results changed if call two was used:

0.00000000000000246374
 1.01690323906836477263
 1.04051353339583885216

Any ideas about the change in sign for the first value (this switch is fully a function of the call, thus using call two, a negative eigenvalue has never occured so far.

Thanks

Comment: Do you check the value of `info`?

Comment: But the value of the first eigenvalue is so small I would consider it just as 0 , considering the numerical precision, because it is 16 orders of magnitude smaller than the other ones - the range of precision of 64bit double.

Comment: Please, read about floating point numbers.

Comment: The problem is not the very small number, the problem is the difference in values when making the function calls. I can reproduce the results over and over again with excactly the same digits and excaclty the same difference